# Accessing SSAS cubes using WCF data services

Tags: ssas, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a requirement by which I need to retrieve data from SSAS cubes and send it over to OData. How can that be done? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Any pointers to sample code will also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Venkatesh. S

Answer (score 1):

you can use ADOMD.Net to execute the query and send the result with wcf.  Below is the class that I usually use.

```
class MDXQueryEngine : IMDXQueryEngine
{
    private readonly string _serverName;
    private readonly string _initalCatalog;

    public MDXQueryEngine(string serverName, string initalCatalog)
    {
        _serverName = serverName;
        _initalCatalog = initalCatalog;
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(MDXQuery query, Func<IDataReader, TResult> work)
    {
        var connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog={1}", _serverName, _initalCatalog);
        TResult result;

        using (var conn = new AdomdConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(var cmd =  conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query.Expression;
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    result = work(reader);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, could you possible elaborate on your answer? I am new to the whole MDXQuery world, ideally could you provide a sample requesting an execution and populating a model.

Comment: Just to add, that ideally Iw ould be looking at a solution that would integrate with EF. Let's say I have a model structure and I define a query based on models. A simple sample would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can query SSAS cubes using LINQ and ADO.NET Entity Framework. 
You will need SSAS Entity Framework Provider in order to be able to do that: 
http://agiledesignllc.com/products

This option makes building WCF Data Services straightforward and trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is SSAS cubes. Not sure about specific frameworks as such to do this.
But one possible solution: 
Wrap the Cube (MDX) with a store procedure. (Access SSAS with MDX from SP)
You can create WCF data service, add an EM and specify stored procedure for EM. You should be able to expose them as oData.

Comment: More on how to access MDX through stored proc: you can use openquery: SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linked_server_olap,mdx_query )

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I' more looking from a WCF data provider standpoint. Whether to write a custom provider or reflection provider to get the underlying data directly.